# How to peridically update objects in a Qt Quick scene efficiently

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have an abstract class representing data objects. Each object represents one data item. The derived classes implement the function `updateValue()` that gets called periodically in a thread to compute new values. All these classes are from a **non-Qt** C++ library.
Something like:

```
class DataObject
{
    double value;
    virtual void updateValue() = 0;
};
```

At present, I have several types of `QWdiget` based display widgets, each widget tied to a `DataObject`. Something like:

```
class DisplayWidget
{
    DataObject *dataObject;
    virtual void updateDisplay() = 0;
};
```

The widgets could be simple `QLabel` boxes, `Qwt`-based dials, gauges etc. The application has multiple *pages*, each page containing several of such widgets. At every 100ms or so (`QTimer` tick), I iterate through all widgets in the current page and call `updateDisplay()` for each of them to update their display.

NOW: I want to have some shiny Qt Quick based *widgets*/pages, that I can generate using qml files. I can use a `QQuickWindow` container widget on a page, whose contents are loaded from a specified qml file at runtime.

My question is how do I efficiently export/map my C++ `DataObject` objects to corresponding QtQuick widgets so that I can periodically update the display?

- Since `DataObject` class and its children are from a **non-Qt** library, I cannot create properties and notifier signals in those classes
- I can of course create wrapper class object for each object that needs to be displayed in QtQuick window. This wrapper class will need to be derived from `QObject` and have properties and notifier signals. Then periodically on display timer tick, I'll need to emit the notifier signal (may be after checking if the corresponding data object's value has actually changed since the last update).
- When the QML file is loaded, I'll need a way to dynamically create the wrapper objects for each DataObject that the file needs.

Is this the most efficient and elegant way to do this? I may need about a hundred display widgets on a page.

Comment: I would create some proxy object that contains a map (name of widget => value) that will be visible for  both C++ and QML, So in C++ you will update the map and from QML you can read these values in a frequency you need and get the updated values at this moment.

Comment: How about `QAbstractListModel`? It functions almost like the `ListModel` QML type. You create and manage it from C++ but you can use it in places where models are used, e.g. `ListView`, `ComboBox`, `Repeat`, etc.

Comment: "I can of course create wrapper class object for each object that needs to be displayed in QtQuick window. This wrapper class will need to be derived from QObject and have properties and notifier signals. Then periodically on display timer tick, I'll need to emit the notifier signal (may be after checking if the corresponding data object's value has actually changed since the last update)." - Didn't you just answer you own question there?

Comment: @JesperJuhl My worry is that if I have 100 widgets (or whatever they are called in Qt Quick world) on a page, there'll be so many signals being emitted in every display cycle. If the data values don't change frequently, there won't be much, of course. But I was wondering if I should have a timer tick signal handler in QML Javascript to update the display of all widgets instead.

Comment: @folibis That was exactly the alternative I had in mind. I will write a handler function in Javascript in QML that will be connected to the timer tick signal. In the handler function, iterate over all widgets and update their display.

Comment: Which is more efficient? In QML:
A declarative statement like
```
displayObject.text = dataObject.value
```
where dataObject is a QObject derived class object with `value` property and a notifier signal.
OR
```
onDisplayTimeout: {
displayObject.text = dataObject.value
}
```
where dataObject is some proxy object that can provide the value of the parameter, similar to what @folibis suggested.

Comment: If it is `QObject` based, you will be making `value` a Q_PROPERTY with the corresponding `valueChanged()` signal. Then, the usage will be declarative `{ text: dataObject.value }` so QML would automatically react to change values.